# Convert a RenderTargetBitmap to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, bitmapimage, rendertargetbitmap

How can I convert a RenderTargetBitmap to BitmapImage in C# XAML, Windows 8.1?

I tried

```
// rendered is the RenderTargetBitmap 
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await randomAccessStream.WriteAsync(await rendered.GetPixelsAsync());
randomAccessStream.Seek(0); 
await img.SetSourceAsync(randomAccessStream);
```

But it always gives error at

```
img.SetSourceAsync(randomAccessStream);
```

There are many ways in WPF but in WinRT? How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the one that worked
[Sharing render to bitmap image in windows phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838278/sharing-render-to-bitmap-image-in-windows-phone-8-1)

turned out that i just can't fill the stream directly using

```
stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());
```

you have to use bitmap encoder , final working code :

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var buffer = await rendered.GetPixelsAsync();
      //  await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, (uint)buffer.Length, InputStreamOptions.None);
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
        encoder.SetPixelData(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
            (uint)rendered.PixelWidth,
            (uint)rendered.PixelHeight,
            DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
            DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
            buffer.ToArray());
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        await img.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        preview.Source = img;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this :

```
  var bitmap = new  RenderTargetBitmap();

  await bitmap.RenderAsync(elementToRender);

  image.Source = bitmap;
```

Reference : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20648.using-the-rendertargetbitmap-in-windows-store-apps-with-xaml-and-c.aspx

**UPDATE :**

Another Refs.. may help :

- [Sharing render to bitmap image in windows phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838278/sharing-render-to-bitmap-image-in-windows-phone-8-1)
- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597 .

**UPDATE 2 :**

Try this one :

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> ByteArrayToBitmapImage(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());
        stream.Seek(0);

        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
        return bitmapImage;
    }
```

Ref : [C# Windows 8 Store (Metro, WinRT) Byte array to BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107576/c-sharp-windows-8-store-metro-winrt-byte-array-to-bitmapimage)

Comment: dude thanks, yep but i Just want the randomAccessStream and it always crashes or any type of streams :D I just need the bytes or stream that i can use later to create another bitmapimages

Comment: What is the error message or the exception type ? any screenshots ? .. Answer updated

Comment: dude the  "Sharing render to bitmap image in windows phone 8.1" post is the one that worked, turned out that i have to fill the stream using  bitmap encoder not directly from the stream.WriteAsync(buffer);
thanks a lot for your help :)